# Angle of a cube's diagonal to one of its sides.

Tags: geometry

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $\theta$ be the angle between one of the $n$-cube's edges and its longest space diagonal. What is the measure of $\theta$ as $n$ goes to infinity?

My thoughts lead me to believe $\theta$ goes to $\pi/2$, but I have no means to prove it.

Comment: By "side", do you mean an edge or do you mean a cell ("face" of dimension $n - 1$) of the $n$-cube? If you mean a cell, then an answer has been posted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant edge. Fixed that.

Comment: OK. See the edit to the answer already given; it looks acceptable to me.

Answer (score 1):

The angle between the side and the vector can be found by taking $\pi/2$ minus the angle between the normal to the side and the vector:

$$\text{angle}={\pi\over 2}-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{(1,1,...,1)\cdot(1,0,...,0)}{\sqrt n}\right)={\pi\over 2}-\cos^{-1}(n^{-1/2})\to0$$ as $n\to \infty$.

EDIT: As this was changed from "side" to "edge" the answer is now the second part: $\pi/2$.

Comment: For the angle between the diagonal and an _edge_ you can take $(1,0,...,0)$ as the direction vector of the edge, and then the solution is simply the $\cos^{-1}$ term of the formulas above (which I think confirms your intuition).

Comment: @DavidK Thank you, edited accordingly.